SOQL Subquery error
I have 3 objects wich relate to themselves, they are:

BRV_Carteira__c: Entity that specifies what can be sold to a client;
BRV_CarteiraItem__c: The itens of the BRV_Carteira__c(Master-Detail) such as Product, ProductCategory, etc..
cgcloud__Account_Org_Unit__c: Entity that associate Account
User(cgcloud__Org_Unit__r.BRV_ExternalId__c) and BRV_Carteira__c(Lookup)

I'm trying to get Account and User Id's and BRV_Carteira__c's items in a single query using subqueries.
here is the full query:
  SELECT LastModifiedDate, 
         Id,
         Name,
         IsDeleted,
         cgcloud__Org_Unit__c,
         cgcloud__Org_Unit__r.Name,
         cgcloud__Org_Unit__r.BRV_ExternalId__c,
         cgcloud__Account__c,
         cgcloud__Account__r.Name,
         cgcloud__Active__c,
         BRV_Carteira__c,
         BRV_Carteira__r.Organization__c,
         (SELECT Name,
                 (SELECT BRV_Fabricante__c, 
                         BRV_Produto__c 
                    FROM BRV_CarteiraItem__c)
            FROM BRV_Carteira__c)
    FROM cgcloud__Account_Org_Unit__c
   WHERE cgcloud__Org_Unit__r.BRV_ExternalId__c = '005Np00000494wXIAQ'

and I get the following error:

INVALID_TYPE:
FROM BRV_Carteira__c)
Didn't understand relationship 'BRV_Carteira__c' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Does anyone know if it's possible to do it and if I'm going in the right way?

Apex does not allow multiple levels of subqueries at this time (API v60.0). If you're doing this through the REST API instead of Apex, then it is possible. It will be possible in Apex in the upcoming (nearly completed rollout of) Summer '24 release (API v61.0). Like the existing answer says though, you're not using the correct form of the object name in the subqueries.

You are probably not using the correct API name of the relationship between the tables. When you create a lookup, there is an extra API name that is created for the relationship you create between the two tables.
In this Trailhead module, for example, there's this query:
SELECT Name, (SELECT Address__c, Price__c FROM Properties__r) FROM Broker__c

In this example, there are two tables, Broker__c and Property__c:

Notice the "Child Relationship Name" field on the bottom right. That is the actual name of the relationship you want to use in the SOQL to make that subquery work. You should be using something similar.
See also: Using Relationship Queries

Thank you, man, it was very helpful.
With your tips I could fix it.
This worked:
SELECT Name,
(SELECT cgcloud__Account__c,
cgcloud__Org_Unit__r.BRV_ExternalId__c
FROM Customer_Org_Units__r
WHERE cgcloud__Org_Unit__r.BRV_ExternalId__c = 'Id'),
(SELECT BRV_Fabricante__c,
BRV_Fabricante__r.Name,
BRV_Produto__c,
BRV_Produto__r.Name
FROM BRV_CarteiraItens__r)
FROM BRV_Carteira__c

Cool, remember to mark this answer as the solution for your issue so others can find it in the future. ;)
